# Returning all strings from an array after a specific index

Tags: java, arrays

I have made a command that does something to a player. One of the optional arguments for this is to add a reason and when executed, it would be sent to the user.

The problem is, I have created the command and the reason works however, the reason has to be written with no spaces. (e.g YouWereGreifing!). This is because in the code I have only told it to use the argument with the index of a number.

My question is, how would I combine an array into a string, but only take the values after a certain index in that array.

**Code**
Here is the method I am calling:

```
Main.demotePlayer(player, targetPlayer, "Guest", args[1])
```

and the args[] is being created with

```
public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String commandLabel, String [] args){
```

Comment: I know that this is Minecraft modding, and as such, the interface can be sloppy; could we have a look at a snippet of your code, just to see what is going on? I want to refuse to believe that you are forced to not use spaces; there should be some means of escaping them within the command, or at least some way to add them yourself. I think this is an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Show some code please

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the reason in quotes? E.g. `/demoteplayer johndoe "Stop griefing, dude!"`

Comment: Yeah, given the above edits, you should be able to either wrap your response in quotes and have it converted to a single string (a la @MartinCarney's comment). If you don't want to make your users type double-quotes to allow spaces, *then* you should look into this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the [Arrays.copyOfRange](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange(T[],%20int,%20int)) method?

`newarray[] = Arrays.copyOfRange(oldArray, start, oldArray.length);`